# users down vote with bad faith

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bad-user-behavior

I have a question about my Skeptics Stack Exchange post: [Linoy Ashram - Did she not miss the flag، and still win a gold medal at "the Olympic Games!"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/52180/linoy-ashram-did-she-not-miss-the-flag-and-still-win-a-gold-medal-at-the-oly)

Why do users vote negatively with bad faith?

Obviously many of them are American and Israeli. In an operation **vote down with lots lots of bad faith**.

[image: Bad Faith]

The closing explanation of the question is more than the question itself. What bad faith can be worse than this !?
I just ask for a [video check](https://youtu.be/cK_B0RbuAFg)

Comment: You've also said all comments are bad faith... Do you know what "bad faith" is? You have all the information you need to contribute positively to this site, according to our site rules. We're a forgiving bunch, so please do try again once you think you've understood the site rules.

Comment: I am not American or Israeli, but your question is written in *bad* English and it is super confusing because the video clip doesn't show the competitor at the Olympics. How do you expect anyone to post an answer saying you are right or wrong? P.S the apparatus used is called a **ribbon** not a *flag* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmic_gymnastics

Answer (score 8):

We have a [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) that talks of kindness and mutual respect. What it is missing is a line from the old version that I sorely miss. It basically said "Assume good faith".

Accusing other users (multiple other users!) of acting in bad faith is not in keeping with either Code of Conduct. Do not continue to make such accusations.

Rather than hypothesizing that multiple users are in a global conspiracy to stifle a big revelation that... err... [I still don't know what the claim was. That some gymnast wasn't penalised for some move?], please consider the far more mundane case: the question was poorly constructed for this site, and it was closed and downvoted for all the reasons that were posted in the comments.

I want this question to be fixed and reopened, and for you to get the answer you need, but it has to conform to the site rules.

Please read this [introduction](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users).

Then find someone making a widely-read claim - e.g. a commentator, a newspaper article, a highly upvoted tweet or reddit article. Quote the claim. Explain why you think it might not be true. We can take it from there.

I am worried that your claim will turn out to be "In the official judge's opinion this gymnast deserved a 9.8, but in this Russian commentator's opinion they think it only deserved a 9.4" and it will be closed as opinion-based.

Meanwhile, the commenters have pointed out that the video you linked to is old. If THAT is the claim ("Is this video from the `2020' Tokyo Games?") then edit the question and we can tackle that. If not, please remove the video as irrelevant.

Comment: To be clear: neither did I follow the event, nor do I really understand the Q-on-main— but it it _is_ peculiar that the vid on YT _is_ misleadingly titled, and the athlete in question according to the first news sources that popped up to me seems to have dropped the ribbon in _both_ instances? That's weird. // But for this post: considering the piled up voting, would you really consider editing the question? Or rather start afresh with —well— an 'improved version'? Somehow I doubt it; that now with this count even a stellar edit would be enought to leave that valley…